# Comparing multiple csv file names and group them accordingly

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv

I have for example 4 csv files. I have many other files with the following naming convention with some other files that don't have 'kd' in their name. I want to select the files with 'kd' and do the follows:

kd_2020_2.csv

kd_2020_2_modified.csv

kd_2021_2.csv

kd_2021_2_modified.csv

pp_2012_2.csv

I want to group the two files that have the same name except for the 'modified' portion and then read those files and do some comparison (therefore, kd_2020_2.csv and kd_2020_2_modified.csv will be grouped together and so on).

So far, I got

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import difflib

os.chdir('C:\\New_folder')
FileList = glob.glob('*.csv')
print(FileList)

files=[f for f in FileList if 'kd' in f]
file_name =[files[i].split('.')[0] for i in range(len(files))]

for i in range(len(file_name)):
    if difflib.ndiff(file_name[i], file_name[i+1]) == 'modified':
        df[i] = pd.read_csv(FileList[i])
        df[i+1] = pd.read_csv(FileList[i+1])
```

It is going out of range since I am doing (i+1). Also, this is not what I intend to do. I want to compare each file name with all the other file names and read only the two files with matching name except the part 'modified'. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ``` itertools``groupby ``` to create groups based on the first 9 characters of the filenames:

```
from itertools import groupby 
file_groups = [list(i) for j, i in groupby(FileList, lambda a: a[:9])]
```

This will output a list of pairs:

```
[['kd_2020_2.csv', 'kd_2020_2_modified.csv'], ['kd_2021_2.csv, kd_2021_2_modified.csv'], ['pp_2012_2.csv']]
```

You can then iterate the list and load the pairs and process them:

```
for i in file_groups:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(i[0])
    df2 = pd.read_csv(i[1])
```